# How do i calculate ration width and height of image

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transforms, css-shapes

I want to display the image base on "width" & "height" parameters.
How can i calculate the ratio of the image?
For example, 30/45, i need to change the width and the height based on what the user select. Does it have any formula?

my code

```
.wall {
  background-image: url(living-room-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  /*transform: rotateY(40deg);*/
}
div.photo {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(00deg);
  margin: 50px 10px;
  background-size: cover;
background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/600/200');
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-origin: border-box;
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
div.photo:before,
div.photo:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  /*border-top: 4px solid white;*/
  /*border-bottom: 4px solid white;*/
  /*border-left: 10px solid white;*/
  /*border-right: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  div.photo {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(10deg);
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;

  }
}
```

and i want to calculate the width and height by user selection.

[image]

Comment: `height = width * ratio`, e.g ratio === 50/100 === 0.5, so a 900px wide image would be 450px tall: 900 * 0.5 = 450.

Comment: One way is to use javascript to get the value of the select element and then do some math to figure out what the width and height based on the current value of the `<select>`

Comment: @rayhatfield the dimensions that user select are in cm`.
so i want to be able to find the width and the height of the image based on what he selected.
for exmple 30/45, what would be the new image width and height.
I think that 450px would not fit mobile screen.

Comment: So make the width fit the available space (`100vw` or `100%` or whatever) and make the height `width * ratio`. Maybe I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you're asking, but you can compute the height based on the width. Take a look at this and see what happens when you change the value in the select:

```js
const onChange = e => {
  const preview = document.querySelector('.preview')
  const previewHeight = `${parseFloat(e.target.value) * 100}%`;
  preview.style = `padding-bottom: ${previewHeight};`;
}

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', onChange)
```

```css
.preview {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 66.6666%;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/1200/400') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <select>
    <option value="0.666">30/45</option>
    <option value="0.5">50/100</option>
    <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
    <option value="0.1">1/10</option>
    <option value="2">2/1</option>    
  </select>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ray, is there any way we can talk so i can show my problem?

Comment: can you join [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210943/ratio-calc)?

Comment: Ray i wrote you there my friend :)